# React-native iOS Keyboard is too large

Tags: ios, react-native

I created a new React-Native project and added a `TextBox` and `TabBar`, but the `UI` is looking weird.

Firstly, the keyboard component is too large.
Secondly, overall UI is looking double scaled.

The picture took an `iPad Air` simulator but it can see the same thing on `iPhone 5s` simulator.

I think it causes from screen ratio and the device's resolution density because it did not happen on kinds of `16:9` ratio devices.

I think if some devices have not widescreen ratio, UI goes to big include keyboard component.

Where can I find some information to solve this problem?
Please, could you give me some advice.

[image: Too large keyboard in iPad Air 11.4]
[image: Native keyboard on Reminders same iPad Air 11.4]

Comment: The keyboard that is shown is the native iOS keyboard. There isn't much you can do about its size, unless you implement your own keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Andrew. I added one more picture of Reminders. It is looking ok but mine is not. This is why I thought weird.

Comment: That is because you are running an iPhone app on an iPad, it never looks good unless the app has been set as Universal in Xcode and coded to look good in both.

Comment: It is new information for me. I'm going to try it now. Thank you so much, Andrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by Andrews advice.
Build configuration must set from iPhone to Universal.
Both keyboard and UI scale is ok now.

[image: Solved picture]